# Setting 'syslog' in Robot Framework not showing any details about silently ignored testcases

Tags: python, python-3.x, robotframework

First of all I would like to mention that I'm new to python. I just started exploring Robot-framework by following RobotFrameworkUserGuide. During this, I found ignored test details not updated in '**Syslog**'[ref:](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#system-log) file as mentioned in user guide (file exists before test execution). I had set the environment variables in system path as mentioned in user guide.

> ROBOT_SYSLOG_FILE=C:\PycharmProjects\FirstRobotProject\syslog.txt
>   ROBOT_SYSLOG_LEVEL=ERROR
>
> Platform and Version details.
>
> OS: Windows 10 x64,
>   Python 3.6.5,
>   robotframework-3.0.4, Pycharm CommunityEdition

I ran the test-suite from terminal and it executed, results were generated accordingly.

Current project Directory Structure:

[image]

Comment: what are you doing to cause them to be silently ignored? What is the exact command line that you're using?

Comment: @BryanOakley: I ran the suite from pycharm console with command **robot behaviour_tests**.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for this: "**LOG LEVEL**" should be "**DEBUG**" to write the details of 'silently ignored' cases into Syslog file. Setting the environment variable "**ROBOT_SYSLOG_LEVEL=DEBUG** provided the log details when the tests ran from command line.

Received output in Syslog file:

20180516 10:13:53.808 | INFO  | Ignoring file or directory '.ignored_directory'.